# PHP foreach value in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I am making an `Staff Online` section for members to see weather any staff member is in-game to help them or not. I began tackling this idea with an array of the `Staff Members` account ID's. It looks something like this:

```
$this->view->staffAdmins = array(64, 80, 96);
```

Then I used a `foreach` statement to get the following details for each account:

- Are they logged in?
- If so, use their `ID` from the array and get more information from the `users` table

My `foreach` statement looks like this:

```
foreach ($this->view->staffAdmins as $query) {
    //Are they logged in?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM point WHERE uid = :ID AND zoneid > -1";
    $arr = array(":ID" => $query);
    $this->view->result = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr);
    //Get their details!
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = :ID";
    $arr = array(":ID" => $query);
    $this->view->staffmem = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
    $this->view->name = $this->view->staffmem[0]['name'];
    $this->view->truename = $this->view->staffmem[0]['truename'];
    if ($this->view->result == 1){
        echo $this->view->truename;
    }
}
```

That returns the following output:

```
Hulu is Online
Cookiez is Online
```

Which is exactly what I need, but it outputs that at the very top of the page, which is not what I need. And when I try to put `echo $this->truename;` in the correct spot on the actual page it renders to, the output is

```
Cookiez is Online
```

It only gets the second staff member's `ID (80)` in the array, while we are both logged in at the same time.

Also, this is the code I am using to `attempt` to get same output as the one the working `foreach` statement. This is on the page the class renders too.

```
foreach ($this->staffAdmins as $staff){
    if ($this->result == 1){
        foreach ($this->staffmem as $logged){
        echo $logged['truename'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a array for logged in users like this

```
$arr_logged_users = array(); // array to store logged in users

foreach ($this->view->staffAdmins as $query) {
    //Are they logged in?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM point WHERE uid = :ID AND zoneid > -1";
    $arr = array(":ID" => $query);
    $this->view->result = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr);
    //Get their details!
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = :ID";
    $arr = array(":ID" => $query);
    $this->view->staffmem = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
    $this->view->name = $this->view->staffmem[0]['name'];
    $this->view->truename = $this->view->staffmem[0]['truename'];
    if ($this->view->result == 1){
        $arr_logged_users [] = $this->view->truename; // assign here to array
    }
}
```

now you can use `$arr_logged_users` where ever you want like this

```
foreach($arr_logged_users as $val)
{
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, I tweaked it a bit and it works great!